# c# Google search result source code in WebRequest vs. WebBrowser.DocumentText

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I am trying to understand the difference of getting the source code of a google page via

using HttpWebRequest via WebBrowser.DocumentText

```
public String WebRequestNavigate(string url)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            byte[] buf = new byte[8192];

            if (url != "")
            {

                    HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                    myReq.KeepAlive = false;
                    try
                    {
                        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();
                        Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();

                        String test = "";
                        int count = 0;
                        do
                        {

                            count = stream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

                            if (count != 0)
                            {
                                test = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf, 0, count);
                                sb.Append(test);
                            }
                        }
                        while (count > 0);
                        stream.Close();

                    }

                    catch (IOException ex)
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                        myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                        myReq.KeepAlive = false;

                    }

            }
            return sb.ToString();
```

The webBrowser function I am using is:

```
public String WebNavigateBrowser(String urlString, WebBrowser wb)
        {
            string data = "";
            wb.Navigate(urlString);
            while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
            data = wb.DocumentText;
            return data;
        }
```

I need to get source code of google pages. However, the first function with HttpWebRequest giving me weird source code results compared to source code I am getting from the second function such as :

- Altered characters such as % signs etc.
- Weird additions to url page addresses in the source code

What am I doing wrong?
How can I fix that problem?

using HttpWebRequest is a fast and slick way of doing such a thing.

Any type of your suggestions are welcome in surfing through google results and reading source codes in order to retrieve url addresses of the search results.

Thanks

Comment: A web page is made up from *multiple* HTTP requests.  The current Google front page is built from 15 of them.  A bunch of them are images but several are Javascript code.  Which then execute and modify the DOM.  Clearly the outcome is different.

Comment: thanks Hans :) Today I learned that the founder of FC Barcelona is also a guy named Hans. If I show you some concrete outcomes, can you tell me what I can do with them in order to get source code same as the one I get from webbrowser.DocumentText?